# Bridging method with RCT_REMAP_METHOD macro from objective-C to swift, xcode complains: missing @end

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native, react-native-ios

As soon as I added `RCT_REMAP_METHOD(findEvents2, resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejector:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)` to .m file inside of the interface, Xcode started complaining about missing @end.

I am trying Callback and Promise examples from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html while also bridging from Objective C to Swift. findEvents1 with callback works for me, but I can't get findEvents2 with Promise to work.

I added method definition with macro in my .m file:

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(EventManager, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(findEvents1: (RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
RCT_REMAP_METHOD(findEvents2, resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejector:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)

@end
```

Then I implemented the method in .swift file:

```
@objc(EventManager)
class EventManager: NSObject {
    func findEvents1(callback: (NSObject) -> () ) -> Void {
        EventRequest(completion: EventRequest.CompletionHandler (
            success: { (events) in
                callback([events])
            }, failure: { (error) in
                callback([(error?.localizedDescription)!])
            }, cancel: nil)
        ).dispatch()
    }

    func findEvent2....
}
```

I don't fully understand how RCT_REMAP_METHOD macro works, I don't see why findEvent1 works but findEvent2 doesn't. Could someone suggest how to bridge this method?